# VSCode Snippets for Latex: Combining placeholders and curly braces

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'm in the process of setting up a file for personal snippets in VSCode for LaTeX.
Is there a way to combine placeholders (Syntax: `${1:foo}`) and normal curly braces?
In my example I want my code to output:
`\fcolorbox {frame}{background}{text}`
where every variable is a placeholder. My generated snippet code (.json) looks as follows:

```
    "Colorbox fcolorbox": {
  "prefix": "colbox",
  "body": [
    "\\fcolorbox ${{1:frame}}${{2:background}}${{3:text}}"
  ],
  "description": "Colorbox fcolorbox"
}
```

but doesn't work since it outputs and interprets the $ and {} as LaTeX symbols.
Is there a way to fix this and make the placeholders work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the requested result: `\fcolorbox {frame}{background}{text}`

```json
"Colorbox fcolorbox": {
    "prefix": "colbox",
    "body": [
      "\\fcolorbox {${1:frame}}{${2:background}}{${3:text}}"
    ],
    "description": "Colorbox fcolorbox"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved it. I somehow didn't think of arranging the curly bracket that way.